# Application Memory Behavior

Tags: java, memory-management, heap-memory

I am new about memory management. I got one question when I was monitoring the memory of my application. Is that normal the heap memory used will increase by itself even there is no activity is going on? I observed that the "heap memory used" metric keep growing until the garbage collection happen. I thought that the heap memory used metric should not change until there is some activity occurring. Am I correct or not?

Comment: Can you please define "no activity"? Also, how big are the changes you're seeing?

Comment: @Malt no activity means there is no request coming into the application. The changes are generally growing. My xms and xmx is set to 4 GB. What I see from the metrics is it grow from 500mb to 4gb within around 3 hours then GC happens.

Comment: @Matt, in the background, I am emitting metrics to Grafana, do you think that is the reason it grows?

Comment: Yes. Collecting and emitting metrics is certainly "activity".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory monitor tool consumes memory to collect new data.
So it seems expected that the memory consumption increases even when your application does nothing.

Comment: I am emitting metrics to Grafana, do you think that is the reason it grows?

Comment: I don't know Grafana but in a general way monitoring an application creates a low and generally acceptable overhead (in terms of memory and CPU)